# Saving 64-bit integer with QSettings

Tags: qt, 64-bit, int64, qvariant, qsettings

Is there any neat way, short of converting number to `QByteArray`, to save `quint64` with `QSettings`? The problem is `QVariant` doesn't accept `qint64` nor `quint64`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`QVariant` supports `qlonglong` and `qulonglong`. As the documentation says, these are the same as `qint64` and `quint64`. So you can just use `QVariant::QVariant(qlonglong)` and `QVariant::toLongLong`.

Answer (score 1):

What if you store `qint64` as a string. QString supports such conversion: `QString::number(qlonglong n, int base)`, where `qlonglong` is the same as `qint64`. The same for `quint64` - use `QString::number(qulonglong n, int base)`, where `qulonglong` is the same as `quint64`.

```
QSettings settings("config.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
[..]
qint64 largeNumber = Q_INT64_C(932838457459459);
settings.setValue("LargeNumber", QString::number(largeNumber));
[..]
```

Comment: There's also a QVariant ctor that takes qlonglong

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to realize that IEEE 754 double format has a 53 bit fraction (don't forget the implicit 53rd bit!) and a sign bit. This allows you to store unsigned 53 bit integers without loss of precision, or signed 54 bit integers. You can store if:

- your qint64's absolute value is smaller than 2^55, or
- your quint64 is smaller than 2^54.